# UILabel attributed label in table cell doesn't preserve attributes assigned in storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uilabel, nsattributedstring

I've UILabel in a table cell, I've assigned it a custom font, weight and colour in storyboard. In `cellForRowAt` when I change label's value it doesn't preserve the label's attributes assigned in storyboard.

Why doesn't it work in a table cell while it works otherwise if not in a table cell?

```
// this doesn't preserve attributes for name assigned in storyboard
cell.name.text = "Name"
```

To make it work I've to construct attributed string

```
cell.name.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: "Name",
                                             attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: MyFont, NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: .white]
```

Comment: Please show your storyboard screenshot with attributed inspector?

Comment: Make sure you have selected `Plain` for `Text` in Label's property in storyboard.

Comment: It's attributed string in storyboard. There is nothing wrong with storyboard. It happens to all my cell's attributed labels and buttons.